# How can i detect a item in list when user send message Discord Py

Tags: python, discord, chatbot

I'm proggramming a ChatBot with Python and Discord.py but i have a problem.

I wannt detect user's message then if it includes a item who there's in my LIST , my Bot will Send A Message. I don't know how can i do that can you help me ?
there is my code

```
import discord
import requests 
import time


howareu = ["how are you", "how do you feel today", "are you okay"] # LIST


class MyClient(discord.Client):


    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as', self.user) # Bot Started


    async def on_message(self, message): # Bot
        # don't respond to ourselves
        if message.author == self.user:
            return
        

        elif message.content == "Hello":
            await message.channel.send("Hello")
        elif message.content == howareu:
            await message.channel.send("Great and You ? ")



client = MyClient()
client.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: Try flipping around the logic check. `elif "Hello" in message.content`

Comment: `elif message.content` `in` `howareu:`

Comment: @MikeClark Thank You Bro

Answer (score -1):

There are many different ways to do that, but the most efficient way is `if message.content in list`

In your case it would look like this:

```
import discord
import requests
import time


howareu = ["how are you", "how do you feel today", "are you okay"] # LIST


class MyClient(discord.Client):


    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged in as', self.user) # Bot Started


    async def on_message(self, message): # Bot
        # don't respond to ourselves
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        elif message.content == "Hello":
            await message.channel.send("Hello")
        elif message.content in howareu:
            await message.channel.send("Great and You ? ")

client = MyClient()
client.run('TOKEN')
```

This should work.

But I would recommend doing it like this:

```
import discord
import requests
import time
from discord.ext import commands

howareu = ["how are you", "how do you feel today", "are you okay"]  # LIST

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix,    # set prefix (for example: "!") **only this is required**
                      
                      case_insensitive=True,    # ignore lower and upper case (commands)
                      activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching,
                                                name=name),  # set name for an activity
                      status=discord.Status.online) # set the status to online


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as", client.user)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # await client.process_commands(message)            this is required if you would like to create commands

    if message.author.bot:
        return

    if message.content == "Hello":
        await message.reply("Hello")  # you also can use message.channel.send()
    elif message.content in howareu:
        await message.reply("Great and You ? ")  # you also can use message.channel.send()


client.run('TOKEN')
```

Don't forget to import commands from discord.ext `from discord.ext import commands`

Comment: I'm not sure why you would recommend to use a `commands.Bot` for OP's use case or even scrap the OOP approach OP took. The second piece of code is unnecessary.